# Python questions about else and elseif

Tags: python

Why or what is the purpose of putting elseif statement if you can just just put a print statement at the end?

Example:
Why do this:

```
Name = “Jane”
if name == “Plate”:
     print (“incorrect”)
elif:
     print (“correct)
```

When you can just do this

```
Name = “Jane”
if name == “Plate”:
     print (“incorrect”)
print (“correct)
```

Comment: Did you try out your code in the interpreter, sir?

Comment: The first code snippet is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `elseif`, doesn't exist in python, use `elif`

Comment: @Michael Butscher, actually, they are both..

Comment: @musicamante I oversaw the uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes off course! It will work like that but it's only for this condition in which you have only one condition so the compiler checks whether it's true or not but what if there's more than one conditions ?? Also not using elif will allow the program to output the other print statement, but using elif or else if will allow to check the condition and give the output.

Here you're simply using an if condition statement if it's true it will give you output otherwise it will not go inside the if condition. For more conditions you have many options either do it in your way but using if statement Everytime will allow the compiler to go through every statement and by using if else or if-elif-else will reduce the time to compile the program.

So, using if statement each time will take so much time to compile.
Using else if reduces the no of comparisons.

I hope this helps

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you Singhal

Answer (score 0):

Using elif (not elseif) allows for a more complex control flow.
For example:

```
if a:
    bla()
else:
    foo()
bar()
```

As long as bla() or foo() don't raise an exception, bar() will run for both cases.
Another example, where elif is useful:

```
if a:
    bla()
elif b:
    foo()
else:
    bar()
foobar()
```

Here, the it is possible that both a and b will be True (or truthy :) together, however, foo() will only run if bla() a evaluated to False and b evaluated to True. bar() will only run if both a and b evaluated to False. foobar() will run regardless, as long as none of the above functions didn't raise.